# Euclidean Geometry Circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In the diagram below, XY is a chord of the circle that goes through X, Y and Z. WZ is a tangent to the circle. 
XZ = YZ
XZW = x-30 degrees
XZY = 4x

I want to calculate the value of x in order to move on to the next steps. Any advice or tips on where to start?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THImM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Just use the simple angle and chord rules.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes perfect sense. I really appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

$\angle XZW = \angle XYZ = \angle YXZ$. From triangle $XYZ$, $$2(x-30^\circ)+4x = 180^\circ$$ and hence $6x = 240^\circ$ and $x = 40^\circ$

Comment: Where is the 6x coming from?

Comment: Expand the equation $2(x-30^\circ)+4x = 180^\circ$ to get $2x - 60^\circ + 4x = 180^\circ$.